# How can I disable console password-authentication on a Juniper EX4500 switch?

Tags: console, junos

I am building a system that automatically configures Juniper and Cisco switches from the console based on user input from a web UI.  I will have a full-time console connection to these devices; however, on occasion the server must be rebooted... thus forcing the system to respawn the console connections.

I want to set up the console access to my Juniper EX4500 without a password; however, my attempts so far at doing this haven't been successful.

I tried...

```
set system authentication-order [] ports console insecure
set system authentication-order [] ports console type vt100
```

I still get prompted for a password when I make the console connection.  If this was a Cisco, it would be fairly easy; however, I can't seem to find the right JunOS magic.

I realize I could just add some code to authenticate via console, but I'd really like to bypass this if possible.  Security is not a concern in this situation.

How can I remove password authentication from the console of my Juniper EX4500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the console to insecure it will prevent root access as well as superuser access or those with ID of 0.

I don't know of any system option that would override this, and you'd need that level of access to make configuration changes.

I think you're only option is to pass the credentials.

(you can always call JTAC and they might be able to find something, I'm just basing my answer on what I see available within the CLI commands that I understand)

Comment: I don't need the `insecure` keyword, and even when I delete that option I still get prompted for a password.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the BSD layer of the operating system is going to REQUIRE you to login. Even out of the box, you login as "root" with no password.

Comment: @Mike, here's what I'm referring to:  http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.4/topics/task/configuration/port-console-and-auxiliary-configuring.html?searchid=1334858707988